# Cut off full path after share path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to export everything after share path like below. Is there anyway to do this using `Split-Path`? Example:

What I have returned in the File is: C:\Data2\Documents\TEST2\TEST2_1\TEST2_2

What I would like to see after the split-path is: TEST2\TEST2_1\TEST2_2

Code:

```
$Shares = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Filter "not name like '%$'" |
          Select path
$results = @()
foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
    $results += Get-ChildItem -Path $Share.Path -Recurse |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
}
$results
$results | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Output\list.txt"
```

---

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Filter "not name like '%$'" | Select path
```

Output:

```
path
----
C:\Data2\Documents
C:\IT_Information
```

`list.txt` output:

```
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST2
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST3
C:\Data2\Documents\1.txt
C:\Data2\Documents\2.txt
C:\Data2\Documents\3.txt
C:\Data2\Documents\4.txt
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST\5.txt
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST\6.txt
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST\7.txt
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST2\TEST2_1
C:\Data2\Documents\TEST2\TEST2_1\TEST2_2
C:\IT_Information\TEST
C:\IT_Information\TEST2
C:\IT_Information\TEST3
C:\IT_Information\1.txt
C:\IT_Information\2.txt
C:\IT_Information\3.txt
C:\IT_Information\4.txt
C:\IT_Information\TEST\5.txt
C:\IT_Information\TEST\6.txt
C:\IT_Information\TEST\7.txt
C:\IT_Information\TEST2\TEST2_1
C:\IT_Information\TEST2\TEST2_1\TEST2_2
```

Desired output:

```
TEST
TEST2
TEST3
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
TEST\5.txt
TEST\6.txt
TEST\7.txt
TEST2\TEST2_1
TEST2\TEST2_1\TEST2_2
TEST
TEST2
TEST3
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
TEST\5.txt
TEST\6.txt
TEST\7.txt
TEST2\TEST2_1
TEST2\TEST2_1\TEST2_2
```

Comment: Splitting `C:\IT_Information\TEST\5.txt`, I would expect you want `5.txt`, not `TEST\5.txt` like you said. Because `C:\Data2\Documents` is two folders, while `C:\IT_Information` is only one.

Comment: @gms0ulman The OP wants the share paths removed from the full paths, so that only the paths relative to the shares remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a regular expression from the share paths and replace them when they occur at the beginning of a path:

```
$Shares = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Filter "not name like '%$'"  |
          Select-Object -Expand Path

$re = ($Shares | ForEach-Object {[Regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
$results = foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
    (Get-ChildItem $Share -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand FullName) -replace "^($re)\\"
}
```